# Excel's Sum() with second parameter

Tags: excel, math, sum

I have a excel file with the following cell data:

```
A1: 1
A2: 2
A3: 3
A4: 4
```

I want to sum over every cell but add a certain value on every value of A1-A4.

So assuming I want to add the value 8, it looks like this:

```
(1+8)+(2+8)+(3+8)+(4+8)
```

I do this with `=SUM((A1:A4)+8)` but the result is 9, which is wrong (in my sense). How can I do this?

I know, I can just do `=SUM(A1:A4) + 4*8`. But this is just a simple example for this question, in reality I do something like

```
(1+8)^2 + (2+8)^2 + (3+8)^2 + (4+8)^2
```

Comment: Your SUM formula will work - `=SUM((A1:A4)+8)`......but it's an "array formula" and therefore needs to be entered with the key combination CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - SUMPRODUCT circumvents the need for "array entry"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

**=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4+8)**

This adds 8 to each element being summed.